# message sent to deallocated instance using Pinterest SDK

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, pinterest

I'm using the Pinterest iOS SDK to share an item in my iPad app. The following snippet of code will always crash with a `message sent to deallocated instance` on the line with the comment:

```
NSString *clientId = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"1431665"];
NSLog(@"clientId: %@", clientId);
Pinterest *pinterest = [[Pinterest alloc] initWithClientId:clientId];
NSLog(@"gone: %@", clientId); // <- CRASH!
```

I'm using `NSMutableString stringWithString` to simulate the conditions in my app. I don't actually use that line in my code.

Even if don't output the `clientId` on the last line, the app crashes when leaving the block. I assume it's because ARC is trying to release the reference which has already been deallocated.

It seems like the Pinterest SDK must be doing something wonky and trashing the string I'm passing in. Is there some way I can get around this while they fix their code?

**EDIT 1**

Simplified the test case.

**EDIT 2**

It looks like the Pinterest SDK is consuming the `clientId` argument. Based on the [clang ARC documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#consumed-parameters), the way to indicate this to clang is to indicate this with `__attribute((ns_consumed))`.

**New question**: Is it possible to indicate this to ARC without modifying the signature of the method to add the attribute?

**EDIT 3**

So this works, but it's ugly as sin? Is there another way?

```
NSString *clientId = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"1431665"];
[clientId performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"retain")]; // <- UGLY!
NSLog(@"clientId: %@", clientId);
Pinterest *pinterest = [[Pinterest alloc] initWithClientId:clientId];
NSLog(@"gone: %@", clientId);
```

Comment: Logically this problem doesn't make much sense.  You have made an autorelease object, which will be released upon the next drain of the autorelease pool.  I've never heard of anyone using "consumed" parameters in Obj-C (probably because I can't think of any situation where it would be useful).  ARC will not release the variable you have created because it is an autorelease variable.  Is PInterest an ARC compatible library?  I can't believe they would be failing so hard in a simple init method.  Where are the docs?

Comment: docs are [here](http://developers.pinterest.com/ios/), but there's not much there

Comment: So I have to actually install the framework to view the docs?  Lame...

Comment: I think that if what you say is true, then you should just send a copy of the string to PInterest (`[clientId copy]`)

Comment: ARC will still try to deallocate the consumed copy when leaving the block. That's what I was trying to achieve with `NSMutableString stringWithString`. Sending `copy` to an `NSString` will just return the same string.

Comment: I know that copy returns the same string, *but* as a side effect it retains it also (which is what you are achieving by your hack).  So the copy method is like the ARC-approved way of doing it.  Wait, are you saying that you want this clientId variable to be available outside the scope it was declared in?

Comment: It still doesn't work. ARC can't be tricked that easily it seems.

Comment: This seems very odd to me.  It seems like the reason it works is because you are forcing a memory leak.  Just to be clear, that log line is *directly* after the pinterest call as written above?  It is not in another block or another method or something like that right?  It is written *exactly* as you wrote it above?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31840/discussion-between-scompt-com-and-borrrden)

Comment: @scompt.com hi :) 
do you fixed this bug please? 
i faced the same problem two, and i don't know how to fix it.
thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

What I did was make a static variable that represented the Pinterest class:

```
//I put this outside my @implementation code at the top of my m file
static Pinterest *_pinterest = nil;

// instantiating
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    _pinterest = [[Pinterest alloc] initWithClientId:clientId];
});
```

I think that Pinterest assumed that everyone would use their class as a static singleton because that's probably what they do internally. To be fair, I don't foresee using multiple client ID's with a single app in most cases. I agree, though, this is a stupefying oversight on their part. They didn't even document this behavior, what were they thinking?!

Comment: hi 
can you explain your answer more please? 
i'm using swift, and i can't understand what u meant by ur answer..

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround, which seems to be the least hacky of the ideas so far is this wrapper class that doesn't use ARC:

```
+ (void) createPinWithClientId:(NSString *)clientId
                      imageURL:(NSURL *)imageURL
                     sourceURL:(NSURL *)sourceURL
                   description:(NSString *)descriptionText {

    Pinterest *pinterest = [[Pinterest alloc] initWithClientId:clientId];
    [pinterest createPinWithImageURL:imageURL
                           sourceURL:sourceURL
                         description:descriptionText];
}
```

The key is to disable ARC for the class, which keeps the runtime from deallocating the `clientId`.

Comment: how do you disable the ARC?
what did you mean by that? 
i'm using swift, and this SDK is disaster really !