# Share Pin using Pinterest SDK

Tags: ios, swift, pinterest

I'm trying to post a pin from my app to `Pinterest`.

I followed there Documentation : [iOS Pin It SDK](https://developers.pinterest.com/ios/).

It's so simple, but each time I try to pin the image the app raise an exception, or the Pinterest app opened normally but when I pin the image I got this error:

[image: error in client id]

It seems like there is a problem in get the right **client id**.

I searched about this problem and I found this result:
[message sent to deallocated instance using Pinterest SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17139092/4498576)
, but it didn't work for me!

My code:

```
var pin = Pinterest(clientId: "1446186", urlSchemeSuffix: "prod")
var urll = NSURL(string: "http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-  samples/200/287.jpg")!
var sourceURL = NSURL(string: "http://placekitten.com")!
pin.createPinWithImageURL(urll, sourceURL: sourceURL, description: "Pinning from Pin It Demo")
```

Comment: @suthar i edited my post, check it please.

Comment: checking wait some time

Comment: Shouldn't your urlSchemeSuffix be something like "pin18571937652947"? That's what they have as an example [here](https://developers.pinterest.com/ios/).

Comment: @EricD. yeah it's something we add it in the Info.plist of the app.

Comment: i found the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/27668986/4498576

Comment: https://github.com/FarisAlbalawi/PinterestUISwift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following code....its i am using in my project...

```
_pinterest = [[Pinterest alloc] initWithClientId:@"XXXXX" ];
NSString *imageKey =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Url];
NSString *captionKey = TempCaption;

NSLog(@"pinterest :%@ -- %@",imageKey,captionKey);
NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageKey]];
NSURL *sourceUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:kServiceStoreLink];
NSString *descrStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",captionKey];
[_pinterest createPinWithImageURL:imageUrl
                        sourceURL:sourceUrl
                      description:descrStr];
```

Comment: add pin id in url types in info.plist

Comment: to be more sure, from where we get the client_id?

Comment: refer this link http://www.codeholic.in/how-to-generate-pinterest-client-id-and-secret-key/

Comment: thanks so mush
but in step 3, when i press sign it i got this error: 
"You are not permitted to access that resource"
why?